# Collection view height changes when playing fullscreen option in AVPlayerview Controller

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

I have place two segment `UIButtons` say `UIButton` 1 and `UIButton` 2.In `UIButton` 1 it displays `UICollectionView` with out video view. In `UIButton` 2 I am showing a video view in it. I have problem in playing video in fullscreen.

(While exiting from fullscreen option my `UICollectionView` Y value getting changed)

```
    if self.titleLabel.text == "RECIPES" {
        self.alertView.isHidden = true         
        let layout = orderCollection.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let recipeCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "recipeVideoCell", for: indexPath) as! recipeVideoCell
        if videoView.isHidden == true {
            self.recipeSegment.isHidden = false
            self.orderCollection.frame.origin.y = 180.0
            recipeCell.recipeBook.kf.setImage(array[indexPath.row].media_thumb!))
            recipeCell.bookName.text    = videoBookArray[indexPath.row].title     
        } else {
            self.recipeSegment.isHidden = false
            self.orderCollection.frame.origin.y = 390.0
            let url = URL(string: VIDEOURL HERE)
            let player = AVPlayer(url:url!)
            let av = AVPlayerViewController()
            av.player = player
            av.view.frame = self.videoView.bounds
            self.videoView.addSubview(av.view)
            player.play()
            }

        return recipeCell    
        }

    return cellB
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you even want to display a `UICollection` or a `UIView` on a `UIButton`?

Comment: @PGDev I m showing a book collection in my first button & video collection in my second button...At first segment video view will be in hidden and in second segment video will appear